# Let $u_n\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ have $u_n\to0$ where $u_n\in C_c^\infty$ have uniformly compact support. Does $u_n\to0$ in $C_c^\infty$?

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes

Suppose we have functions $u_n\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$ with support all lying in $B(0,R)$, and suppose $u_n\to 0 $ in $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$, i.e. for all $\eta\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^d)$, $$\int_{\mathbb{R}^n} u_n \eta\,\mathrm{d}x\xrightarrow{n\to\infty}0$$ then is it true that $\partial^\alpha u_n\to 0$ uniformly for all $\alpha$?

The reason I'm asking this is because in Hörmander's *The Analysis of Linear Partial Differential Operators I*, in the paragraphs immediately above Definition 4.2.1, we have the following statement:

> Let $u\in\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^n)$ have compact support, and then recall that $u*\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$ for all $\phi\in C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$. Then in fact, the map $$\phi\mapsto u*\phi,\quad C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)\to C_c^\infty(\mathbb{R}^n)$$ is continuous.

However, I'm struggling to prove this fact.

Comment: Definitely not: $\varphi(x)\sin(Nx)\to 0$ in $\mathcal D'(\mathbb R)$ as $N\to\infty$ for any compactly supported smooth function $\varphi$.

Comment: I see. Then how can we deduce that $$\phi\mapsto u*\phi$$ is continuous?

Comment: At the level of abstract nonsense, I think there ought to be an argument from the closed graph theorem (the spaces $C^\infty_c(B)$ are Frechet). But in such cases there is often a simple direct argument also.

Comment: Try to use the Horvath seminorms as in
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/234025/why-is-multiplication-on-the-space-of-smooth-functions-with-compact-support-cont/234503#234503

Answer (score 3):

A comment but I am not entitled. As regards the question at the end, the comment of Nate Eldredge points in the right direction---the result follows from the closed graph theorem since the convolution is continuous on the space of distributions.  Note however that we do not have a Fréchet space here. However it is a strict $LF$ space (Dieudonné and Schwartz) and Grothendieck showed in his thesis that the CGT holds in this context. As regards the first question, let me add that a necessary and sufficient condition for this to hold is that the sequence be bounded in the sense that it is uniformly bounded as well as all sequences obtained by successive differentiation.

Comment: I was thinking of the fact that if you take a ball $B$, and endow $C^\infty_c(B)$ with the topology generated by uniform seminorms on the derivatives (i.e. a sequence converges iff all derivatives converge uniformly, but not necessarily supported in a single compact set), then this space is Fréchet.  $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$ is the union of such spaces.  Now if $\phi_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$, then all are supported in some ball $B$, and hence all the $u \ast \phi_n$ are supported in some larger ball $B'$.

Comment: So use the closed graph theorem on $\phi \mapsto u \ast \phi$ as a linear operator from $C^\infty_c(B) \to C^\infty_c(B')$ with the aforementioned Fréchet topologies, to conclude $u \ast \phi_n \to 0$, uniformly with all derivatives and all supported in $B'$, hence $u \ast \phi_n \to 0$ in $\mathcal{D}(\mathbb{R})$.  Finally, $B$ was arbitrary.  No fancier versions needed this way, unless I missed something.

Answer (score 1):

For a relatively simple proof of the continuity of $\phi \mapsto u * \phi$, use the fact that any distribution is locally a derivative of a bounded function.

To be specific: Consider $u$ supported in a compact set $K_1$ and a sequence $\phi_n \in \mathcal{D}$ convergent to $0$ in $\mathcal{D}$, all supported in some compact set $K_2$. Clearly, $u * \phi_n$ is supported in $K_1 + K_2$. Write $u = D^\alpha f$ for some multi-index $\alpha$ and some bounded function $f$ on a large ball (a neighbourhood $K_1 + K_2 - K_2$). Then
$$
 u * \phi_n(x) = f * D^\alpha \phi_n(x) = \int_{K_2} f(x - y) D^\alpha \phi_n(y) dy
$$
for $x \in K_1 + K_2$. Since $D^\alpha \phi_n$ converges uniformly to zero, and $f$ is integrable, $u * \phi_n$ converges to zero uniformly on $K_1 + K_2$ as $n \to \infty$. The same argument works if $\phi_n$ are replaced by their derivatives, so $u * \phi_n$ converges to zero in $\mathcal{D}$.

Comment: Could you provide a reference for the fact that any distribution is locally the derivative of a bounded function?

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine: For example, Vladimirov, *Methods of the Theory of Generalized Functions*, Section 2.4.

Comment: @MonstrousMoonshine It follows from : if $u$ is a given compactly supported distribution then $|\langle u,\varphi \rangle| \le C \sum_{n \le N} \|D^n \varphi\|_\infty$ for some $N,C$. In general $u \psi$ is compactly  supported distribution  for any $\psi \in C^\infty_c$

Answer (score 1):

Here are two alternative methods:

- You have an explicit formula for $u * \phi$ : it is given by $u* \phi(x) = \langle u,\phi(x-y)\rangle_y$, and you can "differentiate under the bracket". Now if $(\phi_n)_n$ goes to $0$ in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$, you have for any $\alpha\in\mathbb{N}^d$ that $\|u* \partial^\alpha \phi_n\|_\infty = \|\langle u,\partial^\alpha \phi_n(\cdot-y)\rangle_y\|_\infty$ which converges to $0$ (you can work on a fixed compact $K$ because the sequence converges in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ and $u$ is assumed compactly supported).
- You can first try to prove the (weaker) fact : $(u* \phi_n)_n$ is bounded in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ whenever $(\phi_n)_n$ is. Once you know that the conclusion follows thanks to the Montel property satisfied in $C^\infty_c(\mathbb{R}^d)$ : bounded sets are relatively compact (this is simply an iterate use of Ascoli's Theorem). Since $(u * \phi_n)_n$ obviously converges to $u*\phi$ for weaker topologies (for instance the one of $\mathcal{D}'(\mathbb{R}^d)$), the latter is the only possible limit point: the whole sequence converges to it.